# W7 Logstash JRUBY Error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, jruby

I am new to the entire ELK Stack, and I am trying to set up Logstash. I followed all of the instructions (unzipping, setting up config file, starting Logstash). My setup is Windows 7, and my java version is 1.8.0_51.

When I run the following command (pipeline.conf is my config file):

```
C:\Elastic\logstash-6.2.2\bin>logstash -f pipeline.conf
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] 2018-03-15 12:30:05.101 [main] Logstash - 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: 
    (LoadError) Could not load FFI Provider: 
    (NotImplementedError) FFI not available: 
    com.kenai.jffi.Foreign.getVersion()I  
        See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583
```

Here is what my config file:

```
input {
    stdin {

    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4583 doesn't seem like a valid site. I have tried my exact process on a different machine, and Logstash works. I have been trying to look for a solution for about 2 days now. HELP PLS

Comment: codehaus.org is no more, which is unfortunate.  Seems like a lot of people have FFI problems related to permissions.  Can you try running it in a cmd windows that you opened as Administrator?

Comment: @phospodka I cannot run cmd as an Administrator. This is on an enterprise machine and I do not have full access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Resolved on the Elastic Discussion site:

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/windows-7-logstash-jruby-error/124152